# Aplicação android reinicia se ficar fora de foco por um tempo

Tags: android

O meu app é um intermediador de uma solicitação de um serviço, ex: (UBER).
O que acontece é que a tela principal do negócio, que é a que o profissional está se deslocando para ir encontrar o cliente, desaparece depois de um tempo se o usuário ficar usando outros aplicativos, por exemplo realizar uma ligação fora da app.
Quero saber como manter essa tela até que essa solicitação seja finalizada por completo?

Comment: Isso é normal, é assim que o *Android* funciona. A solução depende de cada caso. Leia o que a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) diz sobre o assunto.

Comment: Olá @ramaral, editei a pergunta para melhorar a explicação. Irei dar uma olhada no link, obrigado.

Comment: Desaparece totalmente ou seja o processo é destruido? Ela não aparece em "Aplicações recentes"?

Comment: Ele continua a aparecer em aplicações recentes, só que quando eu clico ele volta para MainActivity.

Comment: @MateusCarvalho O normal é ele voltar para a mesma Activity que estava, mas reiniciando ela. Se você quer saber se isso é mesmo efeito do sistema matar a Activity por falta de recursos, ative, nas configurações de desenvolvedor, a opção "Não manter atividades". Abra seu programa, troque para outro e volte para ele. Se o mesmo efeito acontece, seu problema é esse mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de começar a desenvolver para android você deve conhecer o ciclo de vida de uma atividade (activity).
Quando a atividade não está mais visível para o usuário a aplicação é parada e quando o usuário volta para o app o oncreate será executado novamente.

Quando isso acontece perdemos os valores das variáveis, para evitar isso devemos salvar os valores para recuperar depois.

Há alguns eventos como:

```
//Armazenar valores quando a aplicação é pausada ou parada
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("idade", 16);
}

//Recuperar valores armazenados 
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Dê uma olhada [nesse link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle). Obs: está em inglês.

Comment: Mas isso se a activity chamar onDestroy(), correto?

Comment: Uma correção: o onCreate só será executado novamente se a Activity for destruída nesse intervalo.

Comment: @MateusCarvalho A Activity pode ser destruída sem que o método `onDestroy()` seja chamado.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver dessa forma mesmo :)

Answer (score 0):

Para que sua aplicação mantenha dados em background, a melhor forma que conheço é utilizar Service ou IntentService, que iniciam Threads que permanecerão em execução mesmo depois que o android 'matar' a Activity q tem o layout. Para que seus dados sejam mantidos, poderia salvar em um Service um array/objeto/variável com os dados que deseja salvar, e aí, quando sua Activity for reiniciada, você recarrega as informações! Veja aqui: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/components/services.html

É bom observar que Services precisam ser utilizados com cautela, evitando que estejam em execução sem necessidade.

Comment: Citei as duas classes como possíveis soluções, o link é apenas para ter um seguimento de onde procurar, o que será feito mesmo se o link estiver quebrado, pois é do 'developer.android.com'... a parte essencial da resposta está no texto, é uma indicação, já que a pergunta não é sobre o código propriamente dito, então não vi a necessidade de incluir nenhum código específico.

Comment: De toda forma, isso é "overkill". O que o AP precisa é apenas que os dados sejam restaurados ao reabrir a tela. Isso pode ser feito apenas com os métodos padrão do clico de vida da Activity.

Comment: @DiegoF, não tenho nem idéia porque isto veio parar nas Publicações de Baixa Qualidade... Tem explicação suficiente para não ser considerado "Somente um link", seu voto para deletar não é justificado.

Comment: @brasofilo a outra resposta apresenta e exemplifica como salvar o estado de uma activity, meu voto foi com base nisso, além do que foi citado pelo Pablo também, nem precisa de Services para isso.